# batch file ERROR which says ECHO IS OFF

Tags: batch-file

i have written this batch file code but it has this error i appreciate u if answer me .

the error is that when i choose 2 it gone to ask me to enter desire site but when i write the address it has an error says ECHO IS OFF

HELP ME WHAT SHOULD I DO...

```
@echo off
title trace
:main
echo 1)TRACE GOOGLE
echo 2)TRACE YOUR SITE
set /p choice=          Enter your choice:
echo %choice%
if %choice%==1 ( 
  tracert www.google.com
  goto main
  pause >nul
)
if %choice%==2 (
  set /p s=Enter your desired site:
  echo %s%
  pause >nul
)
pause >nul
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not an error message, it's what happens when you run `echo` without arguments. In other words, you see this because `%s%` winds up being empty.

Comment: so why %s% is empty?when i input sth to it?

Answer (score 2):

To fix your problem use `enabledelayedexpansion` as in a block `%` will expand to the value prior to the block:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
title trace
:main
echo 1)TRACE GOOGLE
echo 2)TRACE YOUR SITE
set /p choice=          Enter your choice:
echo %choice%
if %choice%==1 ( 
  tracert www.google.com
  goto main
  pause >nul
)
if %choice%==2 (
  set /p s=Enter your desired site:
  echo !s!
  pause >nul
)
pause >nul
```

Which should work

Comment: okey thnx for answering my question but you didnt say me whats the difference bitween !s! and %s%

Answer (score 0):

When you have `@echo off` at the begening, and you echo a empty var, would get this message. Try to check your echoed vars, ensure them not empty.